# Audio Not Playing - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio-streaming

I'm trying to set up a client's website to play back an audio file on page load (at his demand, not a preferred feature for me). I have used some simple JavaScript but the audio isn't playing when the page loads. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<head>
<!--other metadata up here-->
    <script>
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
      var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
      thissound.Play();
    }
    </script>

    <embed src="scripts/audio.wav" autostart=true width=1 height=1 id="audio"
    enablejavascript="true">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" onload="EvalSound('audio')">
<!--rest of page>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML5** solution, (IE9+, and all other proper browsers are supported)

```
<audio src="audio.mp3" preload="auto" controls></audio>

<script>
    var getAudio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    getAudio.play();
</script>
```

Auto playing audio with no way to stop it is a horrible idea though.

Comment: What's the best place to drop this within the HTML?

Comment: Put the `audio` tag in the `body` somewhere, and then the `Javascript` goes at the bottom, near the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't have a load event. You should probably attach it to the body.

Comment: I've tried doing this and also adding an empty form using the onload event for that to no avail.